# What should I do with a program directory for its installation?

Tags: tree, directory-structure, opt

I downloaded a `tar` of [Ovito](https://www.ovito.org/), now I don't how to continue. The principal idea is to place this in `/opt`, but is this a good idea? The directory structure is like the following

```
ovito-2.9.0-x86_64
├── bin
│   ├── ovito
│   ├── ovitos
│   └── qt.conf
├── CHANGELOG.txt
├── include
│   └── python3.5m
├── lib
│   ├── ovito
│   └── python3.5
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.txt
└── share
    └── ovito
```

And my doubt is: Is it a good idea place the content of `ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin` in `/bin`, the content of `ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/include` in `/usr/include`, and so on.

This is a childishness but I need an something like a standard procedure to install the program.

Comment: You can use `/opt`.

Comment: That is very elegant, but change the `PATH` variable is less elegant.

Comment: Are you sure? This is my `$PATH` : `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin`

Comment: As long as the path to the binaries for whatever program you want to use appear in your `PATH` somewhere, it really shouldn't matter where it's actually located. Only exceptions would be badly written software with hard-coded references and having additional path definitions for packages that provide shared libraries and include headers for other applications to make use of. Using `export PATH="/path/to/ovito-2.9.0-x86_64/bin;$PATH"` should effectively activate the application for general use.